# Failed to open segment when utilizing m3u8 file with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to replicate the "Replay Buffer" feature of OBS, or at least something similar, with FFmpeg. It would seem segmentation and a m3u8 segment list file would be the way of getting something like this to work, but when I try to use the resulting m3u8 file in FFplay or FFmpeg it just throws these errors:

```
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Failed to open segment x of playlist x
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Error when loading first segment 'EL00.ts'
C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\list.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Any other issue I can find similar to this online seems to be related to encrypted internet streams, which doesn't seem to apply in my case... any ideas?

Full log of command that builds the segments and segment list:

```
PS G:\My Drive\Programming\Powershell> ffmpeg -y `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147.48M -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 `        
-pixel_format yuv420p -i video="Game Capture HD60 Pro (Video) (#01)":audio="Game Capture HD60 Pro (Audio) (#01)" `
-map 0:0,0:1 -map 0:1 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset: hp -r 60 -rc-lookahead 120 -forced-idr 1 -strict_gop 1 `
-sc_threshold 0 -flags +cgop -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 288M -minrate 288M `
-maxrate 288M -bufsize 288M -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 320k -af "aresample=async=250" `
-vsync 1 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_wrap 30 `
-segment_list "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\list.m3u8" -segment_list_size 30 `
-reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format_options max_delay=0 "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\EL%02d.ts"
ffmpeg version git-2020-04-03-52523b6 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv 
--enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf   
  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
  libavcodec     58. 77.101 / 58. 77.101
  libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.101 /  7. 77.101
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Game Capture HD60 Pro (Video) (#01):audio=Game Capture HD60 Pro (Audio) (#01)':
  Duration: N/A, start: 428884.260511, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YV12 / 0x32315659), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc 
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 [sync #0:1] (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[segment @ 000002267f603200] Opening 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\EL00.ts' for writing
Output #0, segment, to 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\EL%02d.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 288000 kb/s, 60 fps, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.77.101 h264_nvenc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 288000000/0/288000000 buffer size: 288000000 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.77.101 aac
[segment @ 000002267f603200] Opening 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\list.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 000002267f603200] Opening 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\EL01.ts' for writing    
[segment @ 000002267f603200] Opening 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\list.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 000002267f603200] Opening 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\EL02.ts' for writing
[segment @ 000002267f603200] Opening 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\list.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 000002267f603200] Opening 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\EL03.ts' for writing    
[segment @ 000002267f603200] Opening 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\list.m3u8.tmp' for writing
frame= 2336 fps= 60 q=9.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:38.91 bitrate=N/A dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.999x    
video:41733kB audio:1522kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[aac @ 000002267f622140] Qavg: 313.398
```

Full log of command that utilizes the segments and segment list:

```
PS G:\My Drive\Programming\Powershell> ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\list.m3u8" -c copy `
"C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Replays\Test.ts"
ffmpeg version git-2020-04-03-52523b6 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv 
--enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf   
  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
  libavcodec     58. 77.101 / 58. 77.101
  libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.101 /  7. 77.101
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES')
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Opening 'EL00.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Failed to open segment 0 of playlist 0
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Opening 'EL01.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Failed to open segment 1 of playlist 0
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Opening 'EL02.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Failed to open segment 2 of playlist 0
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Opening 'EL03.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Failed to open segment 3 of playlist 0
[hls @ 0000013f97f2cc40] Error when loading first segment 'EL00.ts'
C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments\list.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

This is what the m3u8 file looks like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXTINF:10.023222,
EL00.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
EL01.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
EL02.ts
#EXTINF:8.933333,
EL03.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: Both logs are of the segment generation cmd.

Comment: My bad, the second block actually contained both logs, fixed now.

Comment: Paste up to the first few entries of the playlist.

Comment: I added the contents of the m3u8 file.

Comment: Go to `C:\Users\gabri\Videos\FFmpeg\Segment Test\Segments` and then run the command.

Comment: That worked! Interesting that it would be a permissions thing when running console as Admin.

Comment: Oh never mind I see, the segment file doesn't contain a full path the video files, should have been obvious.